# Jupyterlab extension gives a function not found error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have issues with jupyter extensions on ArchLinux. In particular, I get the following error:

```
[W 2023-04-01 18:34:36.504 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in jupyter_nbextensions_configurator. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[W 2023-04-01 18:34:36.493 ServerApp] A `_jupyter_server_extension_points` function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a `_jupyter_server_extension_paths` function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
```

How can I get rid of this error/warning? I tried removing the functions with Pip, but it did not work.
Any ideas?

Comment: When I encounter messages like this, I typically continue. This is because I interpret the message as one open-source program relying on another. These open-source programs need to be updated by their respective developers. Since I do not know enough to suggest updates to the open-source programmers, I continue in my current conda virtual environment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not an error, but a warning aimed at developers of notebook extensions: `jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` and `notebook_shim` respectively, not at a user like you. You do not need to do anything.

It's worth pointing out that the next version of Jupyter Notebook (v7) will not require `jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` anymore as it will come with new extension manager (and a completely new extension ecosystem shared with JupyterLab), so there is very little incentive to address this deprecation warning in `jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` as it will cease to be relevant soon.